# Setting up RADIUS Server for use by a VPN device

Tags: vpn, radius, draytek, vigor

Currently we have a Vigor 3300 router that acts as our VPN server.  At the moment we set up connections for home workers manually in the device.

What I would like to do is remove this extra step and instead allow them to use their Active Directory credentials to login to the VPN.  I understand RADIUS is the way to do this.  Unfortunately the manual for the Vigor is quite cryptic, although it give details on how to set up the unit itself I am unsure about how I set up the actual RADIUS server.

Can any one offer some generic advice on how to do this, or point to a resource on the internet that is idiot proof.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Server supports RADIUS authentication against Active Directory.  In Server 2008, this service is called Network Policy Server (NPS).  Prior Windows named this service  Internet Authentication Service (IAS).  [Server 2008 NPS RADIUS diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb891985(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

See if this answer helps...

[Cisco PIX connected to Active Directory for VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/973/cisco-pix-connected-to-active-directory-for-vpn)